# How to convert string into expression using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

This is the preview of my application:

[image]

Here, I want my **Result TextBox** should give result of the **String** from **Function TextBox**...

Example of my code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmint.Click
    txtResult.Text = CovertStringToExpression(txtFunction.Text)
End Sub
```

> **For example**, If I write `txtFunction.Text = "txtInput.Text"`, then the **Result TextBox** should show Text, *"Hello World"*

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**OR**

[image]

> Note:
>
> **txtInput = Input TextBox**
>
> **txtFunction = Function TextBox**
>
> **txtResult = Result TextBox**

Comment: [**Compile and Run VB.NET Code using the CodeDom - CodeProject**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12852/Compile-and-Run-VB-NET-Code-using-the-CodeDom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, That's simple! You need to change the way you are trying to make the code work...

Follow this few easy steps.

> **Step 1**

[image]

> **Step 2**

[image]

> **Step 3**

[image]

> **Step 4**

[image]

> **Step 5** - Add *ScriptControl Object* to your form

[image]

> **Step 6**

Add this codes to your form.

```
Private Sub TestForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AxScriptControl1.AddObject("txtInput", txtInput)
    AxScriptControl1.AddObject("txtResult", txtResult)
    AxScriptControl1.AddObject("txtFunction", txtFunction)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmint.Click
    AxScriptControl1.ExecuteStatement(txtFunction.Text)
End Sub
```

Now, if you type `txtResult.Text = txtInput.Text` in Function TextBox and click on Submit Button you will get your desired result.

Hope it helps!